# A form should only grow but should not shrink than the specified size, How to do this?

Tags: .net, winforms

I have a C# form on which controls are laid and I have set the anchors for controls. The problem is when I shrink the form the controls overlap. It's fine when maximized. Can you suggest something on this? Thanks

Comment: You can set the minimum size of a form.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you're using WinForms, you can set the Form's [MinimumSize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.minimumsize.aspx) property to the smallest size that you want the Form to be.